# MATLAB Rotate and move 2d object in the same time

Tags: matlab, animation

I made star using this code:

```
t = 0:4/5*pi:4*pi;
x = sin(t);
y = cos(t);
star = plot(x, y);
axis([-1 11 -1 11])
```

Now I need to rotate and move this star at the same time. I tried this:

```
for i=1:0.1:10;
    zAxis = [0 0 1];
    center = [0 0 0];
    rotate(star, zAxis, 5, center);
    x = x+0.1;
    y = y+0.1;
    set(star, 'x', x, 'y', y);
    pause(0.1);
end
```

But this code only moves star and doesn't rotate it. If I delete "set" command then it rotates. How can I combine those two actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the job..

```
t = 0:4/5*pi:4*pi;
x = sin(t);
y = cos(t) ;
y = y-mean(y);
x = x-mean(x);  % # barycentric coordinates

% # rotation and translation 
trasl = @(dx,dy) [dy; dx];  % # this vector will be rigidly added to each point of the system
rot = @(theta)  [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];  % # this will provide rotation of angle theta


for i = 1:50
    % # application of the roto-translation
    % # a diagonal translation of x = i*.1 , y = i*.1 is added to the star
    % # once a rotation of angle i*pi/50 is performed
    x_t = bsxfun(@plus,rot(i*pi/50)*([x;y]), trasl(i*.1,i*.1) );  

    star = plot(x_t(1,:), x_t(2,:));
    axis([-1 11 -1 11])
    pause(.1)

end
```

---

In principle, [**homogeneous coordinates**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) (in this case in the *2D projective space*) allow one to do the same job in a neater way; in fact, they would allow one to use just one linear operator (3x3 matrix).

Homogeneous coordinates version:

```
Op = @(theta,dx,dy) [ rot(theta) , trasl(dx,dy) ; 0 0 1];

for i = 1:50
   x_t = Op(i*pi/50,i*.1,i*.1)*[x;y;ones(size(x))];

    star = plot(x_t(1,:), x_t(2,:));
    axis([-1 11 -1 11])
    pause(.1)    
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But star have to move to oposite corner (top right). When I run your code it goes to top left corner, and since I have no clue what your code means I can't fix it :)

Comment: @Alen, I will add some explanation

Comment: @Alen, btw now the code on top moves the star in the opposite corner

Comment: @Alen, I added some comment, btw now the direction is correct..you may want to try to play with it a little bit..

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to compute the correct transformation on the vectors `[x; y]`:

```
theta = 5 * (pi / 180); % 5 deg in radians
Arot = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
xyRot = Arot * [x; y]; % rotates the points by theta
xyTrans = xyRot + 0.1; % translates all points by 0.1
set(star, 'x', xyTrans(1, :), 'y', xyTrans(2, :));
```

Comment: That's presumably because you're still doing `set(star, 'x', x, 'y', y);` rather than `set(star, 'x', xyTrans(1, :), 'y', xyTrans(2, :));`. You will also need to put `x = get(star, 'x'); y = get(star, 'y');` at the beginning of your loop.

Comment: I just coppied your code: http://screencloud.net/v/k7OJ you see it on this screenshot.